# Frame resizing in wxwidgets

Tags: c++, visual-c++, wxwidgets

How do I capture the modified size of Frame and all its children after user has resized the frame?
Can I fire some event when user has finished resizing frame so that I can store the current size of frame?

Answer (score 1):

You can capture the event in the event table:

```
BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(MyFrame,wxFrame)
  EVT_SIZE(MyFrame::OnSize)
END_EVENT_TABLE()
```

Then:

```
void MyFrame::OnSize(wxSizeEvent &event)
{
  event.Skip();
  ... do something
}
```

Make sure the function is declared in the h file:

```
void OnSize(wxSizeEvent &event);
```